# Why am I getting the error "fatal: pathspec 'a.txt' did not match any files"?

Tags: git

I have created in the windows explorer a file named a.txt.

When I try to delete it with the command `git rm a.txt` then I get the error "fatal: pathspec 'a.txt' did not match any files".
The file exists and has not been deleted.

But after I add the file a.txt with the command `git add .` to the stage, and use the same command again `git rm a.txt` .
The error doesn't occur.

The file is in my workspace, so why does this error appear, when the file is unstaged?

Comment: If it’s not added to the repository or staged then git doesn’t know anything about it and can’t therefore remove it

Answer (score 3):

> so why does this error appear, when the file is unstaged?

It's *because* the file is unstaged.

`git rm` means to remove the file from the index (stage) – and possibly from the visible working tree as well. An unstaged file, by definition, is not *in* the index (stage). Therefore the command cannot be performed.

In that situation you can just say `rm` to delete the file from the visible working tree. That is not Git but the shell you're talking to. If the file was unstaged, that command has no implications for Git.

Note that in the situation you posit, no version of this file may ever have been *committed*. Commits are the only thing Git preserves, so whether you say `rm` or `git rm`, if it succeeds there will be no Undo. Be careful.

Comment: Technically it's an *untracked* file that is, by definition, not in the index. "Unstaged" isn't so well-defined: some people use it to mean "exists in the current commit *and* the index *and* the working tree and has the same contents in all three". But overall, upvoted. :-)